# Ansible 1.9.1 'become' and sudo issue

Tags: bash, sudo, ansible

I am trying to run an extremely simple playbook to test a new Ansible setup.

When using the 'new' Ansible Privilege Escalation config options in my ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]

host_key_checking=false

log_path=./logs/ansible.log
executable=/bin/bash

#callback_plugins=./lib/callback_plugins

######

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method='sudo'
become_user='tstuser01'
become_ask_pass=False

[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: [webserver1.local] => Internal Error: this module does not support running commands via 'sudo'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

The playbook is also very simple:

```
# Checks the hosts provisioned by midrange
---
- name: Test su connecting as current user
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "sudo to configued user -- tstuser01"
    #action: ping
    command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

I am not sure if there is something broken in Ansible 1.9.1 or if I am doing something wrong. Surely the 'command' module in Ansible allows running commands as sudo.

Answer (score 31):

The issue is with configuration; I also took [it](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) as an example and got the same problem. After playing awhile I noticed that the following works:

1) deprecated `sudo`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "sudo to root"
    command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

2) new `become`

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "sudo to root"
    command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

3) using ansible.cfg:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become = yes
become_method = sudo
```

and then in a playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "sudo to root"
    command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

since you "becoming" tstuser01 (not a root like me), please play a bit, probably user name should not be quoted too:

```
  become_user = tstuser01
```

at least this is the way I define remote_user in ansible.cfg and it works... My issue resolved, hope yours too

Comment: The problem is definitely the quotes on the become_user and become_method options in ansible.cfg.  The rpm example incorrectly contains quotes; removing the quotes causes it to work.

Comment: I used this "  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo"  But still show that annoying deprecation warning...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `sudo` directive in the hosts section so that subsequent tasks can run with sudo privileges unless you explicitly specified `sudo:no` in a task.

Here's your playbook that I've modified to use `sudo` directive.

```
# Checks the hosts provisioned by midrange
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: "sudo to configued user -- tstuser01"
      command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

Comment: From what I am reading it relates to running Ansible on a RHEL 6 host and an old version of OpenSSH that does not support ControlPersist. I am still investigating. I will try this tomorrow however. It seems there were sudo config options deprecated in Ansible 1.9.0 and on.

Comment: Turns out we have OpenSSL patched with the ControlPersist feature.

Comment: The question related to the 'new' Ansible 'become' syntax. The older 'sudo: yes' works fine.

Comment: -R SU_USER, --su-user=SU_USER
                        run operations with su as this user (default=root)
                        (deprecated, use become)
  -s, --sudo            run operations with sudo (nopasswd) (deprecated, use
                        become)